# Where are Google Collab's packages installed?

Tags: python, package

I've been having some trouble using packages in google collab because I don't know exactly where they are installed so that I can manage them. Is there a way I can access the folder of the packages so that I can easily see what packages are installed and do things like delete, update and install new ones ?

Comment: Doesn't `pip [list, show, install] [--upgrade] <package>` do the job? The packages are here `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages`. Normally you should not change these files manually.